# How to pass a value to the complete function of load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I want to pass a value to use in the complete function of load() in jquery, something like this:

```js
$( "#myDiv").load( "myFile.html", function( response, status, xhr ) {
    //I need the value here
}
```

Any idea?

Thanks and sorry about my english.

Comment: Where are you passing it from? You should be able to access values through lexical context or a closure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `load` completion callback will be a *closure* over the context in which you create it, which means it has access to the variables in scope where you create it. So for instance, if you have

```
function doTheLoad(someUsefulThing) {
    $( "#myDiv").load( "myFile.html", function( response, status, xhr ) {
        console.log(someUsefulThing);
    });
}
```

...you can use `someUsefulThing` even though `doTheLoad` has already returned, because the closure (the callback function) keeps a reference to it (indirectly).

Comment: I always get amazed by the knowledge people have with details, and how simply they are able to explain it. Thanks !